# How to display an email images on Pbear Html viewer component?

Tags: delphi-xe, delphi-xe2

I just know I must save the images in a temp folder and then use them on Htmlviewer .

But suppose we have an email which contains 5 pictures, so html viewer provides 5 empty frames for the images , some of them are located before the text body, some of them are at the middle and some at the end of the email body . Now  How can I define which frame should contain which picture ! ? and how to insert them to the Html viewer ?!.

(is there any way to do all job in a memory stream ? I mean without saving the images in a folder )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The benefit to using `THtmlViewer` is that you do not need to save the images to file beforehand. The component can request the image data from you when needed, via the `OnImageRequest` event. You can supply the data from any source you have available. HTML emails use `cid:` URLs to refer to resources inside the email itself, usually attachments. When the component asks you for such a URL, you can pull the coresponding data from `TIdMessage` directly. `TIdMessage` supports loading emails completely into memory without using any temp files at all. You do that by creating an instance of the `TIdAttachmentMemory` class in the `TIdMessage.OnCreateAttachment` event.

PBear released `THtmlViewer` into the public domain a few years ago and it is now being maintained as an open source project on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/thtmlviewer/). There are several demos available, include a couple that use Indy 9. You should be able to update them to Indy 10, which is what XE2 uses.