# Installing HTML Components into Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I think pbear's component HTML Components, v 9.45, is just what I need. His free download only has packages for Delphi 2006 and earlier. I have Delphi XE. How would I install his components into my Delphi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this Google code download site [THtmlViewer](http://code.google.com/p/thtmlviewer/).
Seems to be updated to XE2 version plus Lazarus.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9146591/576719) answer to SO question [How to display an email images on Pbear Html viewer component?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9143306/576719).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [Delphi Chromium Embedded](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/)?  This is the Delphi API for [Google's Chromium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_%28web_browser%29), which is used by the Google Chrome web browser.  Several Delphi versions are supported, including XE and XE2.

Unless you only need rudimentary browser support, it makes sense to use an up-to-date browser with solid support for modern web standards.

The repository includes Delphi [sample projects](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/source/browse/#svn/trunk/demos) for VCL and FireMonkey.

Comment: Hi @Bruce, I'm trying to get DCEF going in XE but while the DCEF package installs happily I get no VCL components added (under packages the Components list is empty). Any suggestions?

Comment: Restarted Delphi and there they were. Sigh.